# Preventing other websites to see the 'correct' referer

Tags: security, privacy, http-referer

On my website users can post stuff anonymously.

When they have posted something they will be redirected to their post, let's say:

http://example.com/post/2/title-of-the-anonymous-post

The user who submitted the post and the admins are the only ones with access to that post (until it is made public). Once it is made public the post would still be anonymous (i.e. people cannot see who submitted the post).

However, on that page there are also some external links. If the user decides to click an external link the target website has the ability to log the http referer (which would contain the link to the hidden page). This means it would be possible to find out who posted it once it is made public.

Is there a way to change the HTTP referer (/ referrer) when a users clicks on a link to another website?

By for example first redirecting the user to another url and let that page redirect to the external website:

user clicks on: http://example.com/referer-hider?url={urlencoded(url)}

and let the referer-hider redirect the user to the external page so that the referer will contain: `http://example.com/referer-hider?url={urlencoded(url)}`

Will this work? Or is there another solution for this (which doesn't require client side modifications)?

Answer (score 0):

Since the referrer is provided by the browser to a web server, I only see two ways to insure that external sites don't get a view of this "hidden" URL.

First way would be (as you said) to remove the external links from your hidden page by running them through a redirector which uses `header("location: ...");`).  Yes, that will work.  You might just want to use this in general, so that you can track the exits from your site.

Second way would be to stop hiding this URL.  It won't stay hidden forever, after all.  A Google/Alexa/whatever toolbar hits it, and bam, it's indexed.  So instead, build this hidden functionality into something session based.  Make a script that changes its output depending on session variables, and only allow the hidden content to show up if people have logged in or previewed their post or whatever.

The third (and probably best) way would be to implement proper access control, so that anonymous users CANNOT visit the page with the restricted content.  If you want an anonymous original poster to be able to visit THEIR OWN post, you can send them a cookie, then validate the cookie upon the visit to the unapproved post.

For example, upon submission for approval:

```
setcookie('postkey', mysql_insert_id());
```

Then:

```
$pieces=explode($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$postid=$pieces[2]; // or whatever
if (!isset($_COOKIE['postkey'])) {
  header("Location: http://example.org/");
} else if ($_COOKIE['postkey'] != $postid) {
  header("Location: http://example.org/");
}
```

etc.  You probably want better protection than this, but it should give you some ideas.

Comment: `Second way would be to stop hiding this URL...` You missed the point there! It's not a matter of people / crawlers finding the URL of the post that I'm worried about, it's a matter of outside services finding out who posted it. E.g. if i would have posted something anonymously and I would click the external link on the page. The outside website will know that I was the one who posted it through the referer. Because only the OP and the admins are allowed to see the link while it is being private.

Comment: BTW same goes for your third part. This isn't about securing my site to prevent access. It is about preventing other services to know WHO posted something.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now.  I gathered that it was the POST you wanted to remain hidden, so I suggested protection mechanisms for that.  But if the post isn't a problem and only the identity is an issue, then the redirect solution is your best bet.

Comment: You could still re-engineer your post process so that it uses sessions and hides everything behind a common URL.

Comment: @ghoti close but no cigar.  The domain will still be spilled.

Comment: @Rook, true, but that's not the OP's problem.  He's looking for anonymity for the poster, not to hide the entire domain.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP referer is not transmitted by the browser when a link is going from HTTPS->HTTP.  So a simple solution is to have an https redirect page:  `https://yoursite/redirect?url=...` .  However this page is also vulnerable to [OWASP a10 - Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A10-Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards),  but that might not matter to you.   Another solution that doesn't expose you to OWASP a10 is to use a [free redirect service.](http://www.emailaddresses.com/email_url.htm)

Comment: I cannot access that OWASP page. As a matter of fact I cannot access the whole site. Can you please elaborate in this? Is it about malicious links which use my 'redirector'? E.g. http://example.com/referer-hider?url=some-malicious-link ?

Comment: @PeeHaa owasp is down.  You should read it when it comes back.  That being said,  its not commonly used by attackers.  A good example of where its used is against a bank in a phishing scam to make the attacker's link look legitimate in an email.

Answer (score 0):

The [Meta referrer](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Meta_referrer) proposal from Adam Barth would help with your case; in short you could tell browsers via a `<meta>` tag that the Referer header should be stripped on all outgoing links.

This isn't a complete answer since it's only implemented in Webkit thus far, but it's something to keep an eye on.